# Sum a DataGrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an `Amounts` column in a DataGrid that I need to sum and display in a TextBox. I have tried looping through the DataGrid rows but couldn't find the correct syntax for doing so. The DataGrid is bound to an `IEnumerable` that is based on a `TransactionModel`. Here's the code;

**TransactionModel**

```
public class TransactionModel
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string TransactionText { get; set; }
    public int TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string TransactionMonth { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML Binding To DataGrid**

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" FontSize="20">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction" Width="*" Binding="{Binding TransactionText}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction Amount" Width="*" Binding="{Binding TransactionAmount}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction Date" Width="*" Binding="{Binding TransactionDate}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction Month" Width="*" Binding="{Binding TransactionMonth}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Populating TransactionModel**

```
public IEnumerable<TransactionModel> GetTransactionList()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlString"].ConnectionString;
        using (var sqlCon = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            using (var myQuery = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
            {
                myQuery.CommandText = "SELECT id, text, amount, date, month FROM financesystem.transactions ORDER BY id";
                using (var myReader = myQuery.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var transactionList = new List<TransactionModel>();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        var details = new TransactionModel
                        {
                            TransactionID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[0]),
                            TransactionText = myReader[1].ToString(),
                            TransactionAmount = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[2]),
                            TransactionDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader[3], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                            TransactionMonth = myReader[4].ToString(),
                        };
                        transactionList.Add(details);
                    }
                    return transactionList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I loop through the values that are displayed in the `DataGrid` and sum them to display in a `TextBox`?

Comment: Can you use the return from IEnumerable<TransactionModel> to calculate the sum? If so its easy with LINQ: `int amountSum = GetTransactionList().Sum(model => model.TransactionAmount)`

Comment: @MarcoFatica Perfect, if you post as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the return from IEnumerable to calculate the sum? If so its easy with LINQ:

`int amountSum = GetTransactionList().Sum(model => model.TransactionAmount)`

Comment: Oh man, this answer was a real Godsend. Thank you sir!